# string replacement using SED

Tags: linux, string, sed

I am trying to replace certain functions using SED.
Let say I have some function named,

**AAAABBBB()**

and I need to change this into

**CCCC(nBBBB)**

%BBBB <- this can be any legnth, but AAAA, CCCC, n are fixed length.

How I can do this using SED? or even using other method?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you want to replace exactly. Can you give some examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick one:

```
 echo "AAAABBBB()" | sed -e 's/AAAA\(.\+\)()/CCCC(n\1)/'
 CCCC(nBBBB)

 echo "AAAAFF()" | sed -e 's/AAAA\(.\+\)()/CCCC(n\1)/'
 CCCC(nFF)
```

The idea is pretty simple: Match the AAAA string, then capture the B's in a backreference (1 or more of them). Now replace that with a couple of C's and the backref. Same goes for the other letter.

You are better off with some concrete examples by the way. Otherwise we might not hit *exactly right* on the substitution you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r 's/^A+([^A]+)\(\)/CCCC(n\1)/'
```

Comment: so It can be  AAAAFWEF() or AAAAWGRSFWEF() or even AAAAEGRERGREGREGSADFE(), etc.

Comment: To be more specific,

OSA_MD_GetBlahblahblah() has to be changed into
UISPEC(nBlahblahblah)

Answer (score 0):

You don't give enough information to make a very selective pattern (assuming there are functions you *don't* want to rename) but if you wanted to rename everything like that:

```
sed -e 's/^\(....\)\(.*\)()/\1(n\2)/'
```

That turns 4 characters at the start of the line (AAAA) followed by any length BBBB into AAAA(nBBBB).  I'm not sure where you expected to get CCCC from?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/AAAA\([^(]*\)()/CCCC(n\1)/'
```